# Return entire row after idxmax groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning python and pandas.

I have the following dataframe

```
Date         Category    Sales       Paid
8/12/2020    Table       1 table     Yes
8/12/2020    Chair       3chairs     Yes
13/1/2020    Cushion     8 cushions  Yes
24/5/2020    Table       3Tables     Yes
31/10/2020   Chair       12 Chairs   No
11/7/2020    Mats        12Mats      Yes
11/7/2020    Mats        4Mats       Yes
```

I need to extract the row with the maximum count across all dates against the 'Sales' column once grouped by `Date`.

This displays only one value, the `Date` with the maximum count value present in the `Sales` column. How do I print the entire row for that match?

```
df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).groupby(df['Date']).agg(sums='count').idxmax()
```